# How does jQuery know if there's going to be a callback attached to an ajax promise?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I've been using this for years but I've realized I don't understand something very basic. In jQuery you can make a call like this:

```
$.post({url: url, success: callback})
```

and jQuery will call the callback method when the post completes.

But you can also accomplish it with promise syntax like this:

```
$.post(url).done(callback)
```

The thing that's confusing me is: the `post` method works whether or not there's a `done` callback attached, so how does it know that there is one?

In other words, I could understand it if you had to do this:

```
1 var jqxhr = $.post(url)
2 jqxhr.done(callback)
3 jqxhr.execute()
```

But line 3 is not needed. So how is the `post` able to execute without any explicit `execute` call, and yet invoke the `done` callback if there is one **that gets attached later**?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery returns a Promise object. This happens immediately (ajax is async, so the return will happen immediately, whereas the result of the ajax call is generally delayed by at least a tiny amount of time).

When you call .done() you're actually calling that on the Promise which was returned from ajax.

If you choose not to do that, jQuery doesn't care at all, it just does the ajax request and (eventually) resolves or rejects the promise object. It has no idea, and doesn't need to know, whether you chose to listen to that or not.

In summary, "done" *doesn't* get attached "later" in reality, although superficially the way the code is written could give you that impression.

Comment: So you're saying that this works because the `post` call (line 1) initiates the request and returns immediately. Then line 2 is also immediate. But the actual `post` takes some time, so by the time it completes, the `done` handler is attached. That makes sense.

Comment: But what would happen if you wanted a similar design pattern, except that the thing you're waiting for might need an async load but might also already be ready, and so there was no delay?

Comment: AFAIK this cannot happen - you can try it by creating your own Promise object which resolves immediately with no delay.